# Xamarin.iOS Objective-C Binding Error

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

I am trying to bind: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tsvalidatedtextfield for use with Xamarin.iOS.

So far, I have compiled a static library with the Objective-C code and I have generated API Definitions with Objective-Sharpie.

For two of the properties, I am getting an error:

```
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NSRegularExpression' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246) (TSValidatedTextField)

Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ValidationBlock' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246) (TSValidatedTextField)
```

It doesn't make any sense. As far as I know, NSRegularExpression is part of the Foundation framework, which I have imported (`using MonoTouch.Foundation`).

How would I go about fixing these errors? The binding compiles if these two properties are commented out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace TSValidatedTextField
{

public enum ValidationResult {
    Passed = 0,
    Failed,
    ueTooShortToValidate
}

[BaseType (typeof (UITextField))]
public partial interface TSValidatedTextField {

    [Export ("regexpPattern")]
    string RegexpPattern { get; set; }

    [Export ("regexp")]
    NSRegularExpression Regexp { get; set; } //ERROR

    [Export ("isValid")]
    bool IsValid { get; }

    [Export ("regexpValidColor")]
    UIColor RegexpValidColor { get; set; }

    [Export ("regexpInvalidColor")]
    UIColor RegexpInvalidColor { get; set; }

    [Export ("validatedFieldBlock", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    ValidationBlock ValidatedFieldBlock { get; set; } //ERROR

    [Export ("validWhenType")]
    bool ValidWhenType { [Bind ("isValidWhenType")] get; set; }

    [Export ("looksForManyOccurences")]
    bool LooksForManyOccurences { [Bind ("isLooksForManyOccurences")] get; set; }

    [Export ("occurencesSeparators")]
    NSObject [] OccurencesSeparators { get; set; }

    [Export ("minimalNumberOfCharactersToStartValidation")]
    uint MinimalNumberOfCharactersToStartValidation { get; set; }
}

}
```

Comment: `NSRegularExpression` and `ValidationBlock` doesn't look to be part of `monotouch.dll`

Comment: Unfortunately, yeah, I have no idea how to include them in, NSRegularExpression is a member of the iOS Foundation framework, but not the MonoTouch one. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSRegularExpression` and `ValidationBlock` aren't part of `Xamarin.iOS`.

That doesn't mean you're stuck there. just like you're binding `TSValidatedTextField`, you can bind them yourself.

Once it's done, it's probably better to mark the `NSRegularExpression Regexp { get; set; }` with `[Internal]` and write some custom code to expose a .NET `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`, more natural to use in C#.